# CXF class not found exception for neethi/PolicyComponent

Tags: tomcat, cxf

Can someone explain the cause of this error? I am getting this error only when I deploy the application(in a Tomcat server). On my developing machine and also in others machines this works fine. We run the application on Jetty, Even when I run in Tomcat on my local machine, it works. Is it a access permission problem? When I manually add the neethi.jar file NullPointerException is thrown. any thoughts? I am using CXF 2.3.3

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngine' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-policy.xml]: Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader

context: 
delegate: false
repositories:
/WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@4447393f
] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/neethi/PolicyComponent    
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:163)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110)

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngine' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-policy.xml]: Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader


context: 
delegate: false
repositories:
/WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@4447393f
] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/apache/neethi/PolicyComponent
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:96)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:86)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:64)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:53)
org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:90)
org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:137)
org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:122)
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:89)
javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:680)


net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:163)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110)




root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/neethi/PolicyComponent
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1836)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:157)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext.<init>(BusApplicationContext.java:91)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createApplicationContext(SpringBusFactory.java:102)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:93)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:86)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:64)
org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:53)
org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:90)
org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:137)
org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:122)
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:89)
javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:680)
-******
net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
*****
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:163)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It was something to do with Maven. When Maven builds the final war file it hasn't included  CXF jar dependencies. That caused the problem.